# Merging two columns with different information, python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe with one column of last names, and one column of first names. How do I merge these columns so that I have one column with first and last names?

Here is what I have:
First Name (Column 1)

John
Lisa
Jim

Last Name (Column 2)

Smith

Brown

Dandy

This is what I want:

Full Name

John Smith

Lisa Brown

Jim Dandy.

Thank you!

Comment: `df["Full Name"] = df["First Name"] + ' ' + df["Last Name"]`

`df.drop[["First Name", "Last Name"]], 1)`

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
df.assign(name = df.apply(' '.join, axis = 1)).drop(['first name', 'last name'], axis = 1)
```

You get

```
    name
0   bob smith
1   john smith
2   bill smith
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a sample `df`:

```
df
  first name last name
0        bob     smith
1       john     smith
2       bill     smith
```

You can do the following to combine columns:

```
df['combined']= df['first name'] + ' ' + df['last name']

df
  first name last name    combined
0        bob     smith   bob smith
1       john     smith  john smith
2       bill     smith  bill smith
```